# Quartz.NET how to set next fire on flight

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, quartz

My application uses Quartz a lot and one of the tasks is to trigger the next job execution based on what has happened in the current. So the algorithm is pretty simple - schedule the job, after it triggers for the first time I need to set the time when it fires the next.

In other words, the schedule of my job is not determined and it has different execution period each time.

Maybe I'm completely blind but I can't find the way to re-schedule job from inside the current job and can't find the example of such implementation. So I started to think that I do something silly with Quartz. Am I trying to do something outside of Quartz paradigm and this is not what Quartz for?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334411/quartz-net-rescheduling-job-with-new-trigger-set

Comment: @VolkmarRigo looks like really blind! this is what i exactly wanted to, going to check if it works fo me. Leave my q for a while to see if someone has better idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quartz.NET Rescheduling job with new trigger set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334411/quartz-net-rescheduling-job-with-new-trigger-set)